# blob vs adls gen2 || things that can be done through adls2 but not possible through blob storage

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake, azure-data-lake-gen2

I am new to azure world. I am going through blob storage and adls2. I observed that apart from space constraint and herieracial namespace, everything what adls2 can do , same can be done through blob.

But still people recommend adls2 for analytical workload. Please advise what are things that can be done through adls2 but not possible through blob storage(apart from space and herieracial namespace).

Comment: It has some specific optimizations for analytic workloads, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-introduction#key-features-of-data-lake-storage-gen2

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2):

Data Lake Storage Gen2 makes Azure Storage the foundation for building enterprise data lakes on Azure. Designed from the start to service multiple petabytes of information while sustaining hundreds of gigabits of throughput, Data Lake Storage Gen2 allows you to easily manage massive amounts of data.

Data Lake Storage Gen2 builds on Blob storage and enhances performance, management, and security in the following ways:

Performance is optimized because you do not need to copy or transform data as a prerequisite for analysis. Compared to the flat namespace on Blob storage, the hierarchical namespace greatly improves the performance of directory management operations, which improves overall job performance.

Management is easier because you can organize and manipulate files through directories and subdirectories.

Security is enforceable because you can define POSIX permissions on directories or individual files.

Also, Data Lake Storage Gen2 is very cost effective because it is built on top of the low-cost Azure Blob Storage. The additional features further lower the total cost of ownership for running big data analytics on Azure.

No limits on account sizes, file sizes, or number of files in ADLS

For more information refer this [article](https://medium.com/awesome-azure/azure-difference-between-azure-blob-storage-and-azure-data-lake-storage-comparison-azure-blob-vs-adls-gen2-81af5ef2a6e1) by Ashish Patel

Comment: Thanks Abhishek. My question was more towards practical implementation  
1 If there anything that ADLS can do but not possible through blob
2 ADLS is build on top of blob then why not Microsoft just give option of ADLS to clients instead of Blob and stop blob services for new clients.